# How to find specific chart series ChartGroup index number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am looking for a way to find a ChartGroup index number of specific series (one or more).

For example, I have 10 different series on my chart and I want to edit gap width of one of the series. I can do that using ActiveChart.ChartGroups(index).GapWidth method. But how do I actually find chart group of one, specific series?

I know the series name, but I have no idea how to find the correct chartgroups index. I can type .ChartGroups(1) but it does not work all the time.

Is there any syntax to get up in hierarchy using SeriesCollection("series_name") to find this series chart group?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find an answer, which somebody might find useful.

When you need to change GapWidth of a series, you need to use ChartGroup with index to do that. If you do not know the ChartGroup index like I do, but you know the series and can reference it, you can use the following syntax:

```
series.Parent.GapWidth = x
```

.Parent directly references the series ChartGroup without knowing its index, and you can work further with ChartGroup methods etc.

It might be obvious to somebody, but I post it anyway. I hope somebody will benefit.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, and it works a treat, so thank you!